# ¿Cómo solucionar pantalla congelada de Gluon Scene Builder en Debian?

Tags: font-awesome, scenebuilder

Muy buen día a todos, estoy teniendo un problema con Scene Builder, versión: 8.5.0
Mi problema es al usar los íconos de `Fontawesome`, es decir, cuando pongo un elemento `<label> y` dentro de ese `label` le pongo un ícono, es ahí donde la pantalla se congela.
Mi sistema operativo es:

```
MX_LINUX XFCE for Debian 64 bits

RAM: 4GB

DISCO DURO: 500GB
```

Los gráficos de todo mi sistema operativo usa GTK.
Adjunto una imagen de cómo se me congela la pantalla:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden darse cuenta, el menú de Scene Builder se pone en modo espejo y hasta abajo también, se corta la pantalla.
¿Alguna recomendación?

Comment: También me aparece la pantalla en blanco.